# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I recently changed my application's Kafka client version. And immediately after that my integration tests start failing due to the below mentioned issue with embedded Kafka. This is the snippet from my code which is initialising embedded Kafka broker.

```
@ClassRule
public static EmbeddedKafkaRule kafkaEmbedded = new EmbeddedKafkaRule(1, true, 1, KafkaTopic.getTopics());
```

Here,  KafkaTopic.getTopics() returns a list of topics.
 I am currently using spring-kafka-test 2.2.8.RELEASE and spring-kafka 1.3.8.RELEASE.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;

    at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.<init>(EndPoint.scala:32)
    at kafka.cluster.EndPoint$.<clinit>(EndPoint.scala)
    at kafka.server.Defaults$.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:68)
    at kafka.server.Defaults$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:781)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala)
    at kafka.utils.TestUtils$.createBrokerConfig(TestUtils.scala:234)
    at kafka.utils.TestUtils.createBrokerConfig(TestUtils.scala)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.createBrokerProperties(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:239)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:214)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.rule.EmbeddedKafkaRule.before(EmbeddedKafkaRule.java:109)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:46)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Can someone suggest a fix for this?

Comment: can you share the code snippet too?

Comment: looks like a change in the scala version

Comment: I tried adding testCompile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.8' in my build.gradle but didn't helped. Can you suggest which version to use.

Comment: I have faced similar issued when I switched scala version. Reaplaced all my dependencies with compatible new scala version and it worked

Comment: You can't mix versions like that `spring-kafka-test 2.2.8.RELEASE and spring-kafka 1.3.8.RELEASE.` - they must be the same. Also see my answer.

Comment: Hi @GaryRussell I override the Kafka jars and used different versions(spring-kafka-test 2.2.8.RELEASE and spring-kafka 1.3.8.RELEASE) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

> spring-kafka-test 2.2.8.RELEASE and spring-kafka 1.3.8.RELEASE.

You can't do that; the versions must match.

Also, when overriding the kafka-clients version, you must also override the other kafka jars used by the test embedded broker.

See the appendix for whichever version you are using; for example:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#deps-for-24x